# MacOS react-native picker/select with search field

Tags: react-native, macos, select, input, picker

I am using `@react-native-picker/picker` on macOS to select items in a `picker/select`.

[image]

[image]

But graphically it's not very nice, what I would like to achieve is an effect similar to the one in the image below or something that suits the graphics of macos.
With the possibility of putting an icon next to the text, an input field that allows you to filter the results.

Can you give me some advice?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on what the library allows customization wise. However, this isn't very hard to accomplish without a package. Essentially you want to combine a text field with a flat list and use the input from the text field to filter the data in the flat list. You can then also customize the text in the text field based on what item is selected in the flat list.

Let me know if you have any questions.